# How do I add an extension for this generic data type in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm using the [Mapper](https://github.com/LYFT/MAPPER) library with Swift for JSON.

To get it into a variable you do something like:

`try firstName = map.from("first_name")`

With autocomplete I can see the result of `map.from` is a value of type `T` which is a generic I think.

I want to add a `nilIfEmpty` method like `map.from(value).nilIfEmpty()` so that if the json is just `""` I'll have it be nil. It's a lot more compact than `map.from(value) == "" ? nil : map.from(value)`

How would I write this though?

Comment: Your method has to operate on the return type (String), not the class that `from` is contained in.

Answer (score 0):

You could just extend `String`:

```
extension String {
    func nilIfEmpty() {
        return self.isEmpty ? nil : self
    }
}

map.from(value).nilIfEmpty()
```